# Binding rvalue to lvalue reference

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, copy-constructor

I have the following c++ code (VS2013):

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
    int i;
public:
    A(int i) : i(i) {
        cout << "Constructor: " << i << endl;
    }
    A(const A &o) : i(o.i) {
        cout << "Copy constructor: " << i << endl;
    }
    ~A() {
        cout << "Destructor: " << i << endl;
    }
};

A test(const A &a, A b, A *c) {
    return *c;
}

int main() {
    A b(10);
    cout << "START OF TEST" << endl;
    test(1, b, &b);
    cout << "END OF TEST" << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

When running the code, I get the following output between the "START OF TEST" and "END OF TEST" outputs:

> Constructor: 1
>
> Copy constructor: 10
>
> Copy constructor: 10
>
> Destructor: 10
>
> Destructor: 10
>
> Destructor: 1

3 objects are built: 1 using an integer `1`, and 2 using an object of class `A` (with i = 10).

It's worth mentioning that when the `test` function's argument `const A &a` is changed to `A &a` (not a constant), the program does not compile, giving the following error:

> Error C2664: 'A test(A &,A,A *)' : cannot convert argument 1 from
>   'int' to 'A &'

How is this behavior explained?

Specifically:

1. Why does sending an integer `1` to `test` make A's parameter constructor `A(int i)` work (and only when `const` is used)?
2. Why does A's copy constructor A(const A &o) work twice? (one run occurs when calling `test`, and another when returning `*c`).

Comment: `i(i)`shudder. Please use less daring naming...

Comment: @Gil Did you answer your second question?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How come a non-const reference cannot bind to a temporary object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, calling `test` with the first argument `1` causes the creation of a `rvalue` of type `A`. An rvalue can be assigned to a `const lvalue reference`  but not to a plain `lvalue` reference. If you want it to compile without using `const` you have to specify that the parameter is a `rvalue` reference.

`g++` error is a little bit more informative:

```
 error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘A&’ to an rvalue of type ‘A’
     test(A(1), b, &b);
```

#### `rvalue` can be assigned to an `rvalue reference` or to a  `lvalue reference to const`.

- **Why is that?** `rvalues` are temporary objects or literals. If this code was legal

  `int &r` = 5

  then you would be able to modify `5`.
  On the other hand `lvalue references to const` forbids any change to the object they reference and thus you may bind them to a `rvalue`.

---

```
const A& x = 1; //compile
x = 2;         //error!
A&& xxx = 1; //compile
A& xx  = 1; //does not compile.
```

---

Regarding the second question. You are returning a copy of `A` from `test` so `*c` triggers the construction of a copy of `c`. 
Try returning a reference `A` from `test` to see that the constructor is not called.

Comment: what's the difference between `A&& xxx = 1; ` and `A xxxx = 1;`?

Comment: @dragonxlwang The first is a reference to a `rvalue` (the temporary and anonymous `1` on the right of the `=` sign) while the second is a *normal* variable to which `1` gets copied in.